# Getting file in small packs TCPclient

Tags: c#, client, filestream

This works fine: But the problem is I am getting file from server which is 170mb and its being 
temporary stored on my computer ram (thats my guess).

```
 while (rest != 0)
             {
                rest = rest - serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
                Console.WriteLine("REST: " + rest);

             }

                FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
                fs.Write(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
                  fs.Close();
```

But what if I run my app on a computer which don't have inof ram.

I tried this:

```
   FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
         while (rest != 0)
         {
            rest = rest - serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("REST: " + rest);
            fs.Write(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
         }
              fs.Close();
```

I want it to write the stream which just got in, in my file etc. But this doesn't work.

What am i doing wrong here?

I hope my question is understandable...

Comment: "But this doesn't work" what you mean? what's the result? is just the filestream that doesn't save data into the file?

Comment: The file I am sending from server is 15mb. when I receive it, it is 256mb (sometimes more sometimes less) with nothing in it or sometimes it gets some of data. And the program crash without any exception.

Comment: So is a server problem?

Comment: @Sam Nop I don't think that the server is the problem. But client app is. And I am not sure of what goes wrong becaz it doesn't throw any exception or no errors no warrnings at all. hmm